# HTTP Referer on HTML Frames

Tags: http-referer, html-frames

Say that I have a link from one.com to two.com/A.html. A.html looks like this

```
<FRAMESET cols="100%">
  <FRAME src="B.html">
</FRAMESET>
```

The HTTP Referer on A.html is "one.com", but what will the HTTP referer be on B.html? Is this browser specific?

Answer (score 2):

it'll be two.com/A.html, the link from the container. It's not browser specific, unless the browser is told to send a different referer via configuration

Comment: Thank you! Do you have any reference on this?

Answer (score 0):

It should be two.com/a.html (i.e. the page that has the frameset on it).

Remember that these referrers are set by the browser and therefore can be faked.