# What is the equivalent of top.location in php?

Tags: php

I am using javascript `top.location` to retrieve parent location through javascript

What i wanted to know is there any way to get parent url through php?

I have tried `$_SERVER` with different parameters but i am getting the child window url.

Comment: No way, PHP doesn't know about client-windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`top` refers to a frame object. There is no way to distinguish a HTTP request for a document that will be rendered in a frame from one that will not.

Therefore, there's no equivalent to the client-side `top.location` in php (a server-side language). You can, however, block your page from being rendered in a frame by setting the [`X-Frame-Options`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/The_X-FRAME-OPTIONS_response_header) HTTP header.

Answer (score 3):

Your php server code has no chance whatsoever to know what is going on on the client. As well as your js code can't look into the server.

Answer (score 1):

i used this in my php script...

```
if (...whatever!) { require("location_top.php"); exit; }
```

then in location_top.php

```
<?php // ?>
<h1><a href="scriptname.php" target="_top">Click here to continue</a></h1>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
top.location = "scriptname.php";
//-->
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

When the frame first loads, this *should* be in the HTTP Referer. See [HTTP Referer on HTML Frames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4101336/http-referer-on-html-frames) for details.